# Visual Studio Code mssql extention: SQL Server (mssql) - Unable to connect to server

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I'm trying for the first time to get my project to run in Visual Studio Code. This includes a MySQL database. So I've installed the SQL Server (mssql) extension version 1.7.1. I follow the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/visual-studio-code/sql-server-develop-use-vscode?view=sql-server-ver15

I get to the section "Connect to SQL Server" and enter:

- servername: localhost
- db name: c3
- Authentication type: Integrated

At the end of the section it should connect with the server but instead I get two errors:

> mssql: Error "Unable to connect using the connection information
>   provided. Retry profile creation?"
>
> mssql: Error 2: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

Does anyone see what is going wrong here?
I've re-installed the extension but with the same result.

Comment: A MySQL db and Microsoft SQL Server db are two different things. It seems that there's no SQL Server installed? You might install the free SQL Server Express Version, create the database in there and then connect from Visual Studio Code...

Comment: Oh, I feel so stupid right now haha, No it's really a MySql db that I would like to have (all knex code is meant for a mysql db). Is there an extension for Mysql as well?

Comment: Yepp.. [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.vscode-mysql)...

Comment: Sorry for these newbie questions: but am I right that in addition to having these extensions I also somehow need to install a server (so outside of Visual Studio Code)? I'm new to all of this and have always used an IDE that took care of all that.

Comment: Yes.. you have to install the database server yourself as VS Code is just a client. You might also use somekind of hosted offers (many webhosters offer a mysql server with self service installation)... Or use some other database (e.g. SqlLite) which can also be used without installation, as it's file based.

Comment: Thanks, am installing a MySql server, right now. Not sure if you want to add the answer? I'll certainly accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A MySQL db and Microsoft SQL Server db are two different things.

It seems that there's no SQL Server installed? You might install the free SQL Server Express Version, create the database in there and then connect from Visual Studio Code.

You have to install the database server yourself as VS Code is just a client. You might also use somekind of hosted offers (many webhosters offer a mysql server with self service installation, or use a cloud based database server). Yout can also use a local database (e.g. SqlLite) which is file based and doesn't need a special installation.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following

1. install SQL server in your machine and create Database [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-linux-ver15&preserve-view=true)
2. Create a login and a database user [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-security-get-started?view=sql-server-ver15)
3. If you are Using VS code install [SQL Server (mssql)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-mssql.mssql)    open new
   connection, follow the prompts to specify the properties for the new
   connection profile
4. If you want to login to your server to make sure of your data

   ```
   sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P '<YourPassword>'
   ```